# Unable to do fitting of data using curve_fit()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to fit the function a*x +b*log((x-x0)/c) with data mentioned in the txt file. The x-axis is the injected current and y axis is the gain_X. I was using the function curve_fit() , but it does not works and says "Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000000". I have attached my code below and the text file can be viewed with the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QLIG44ZliOLdOT5QVdDpcUPv4EiQnFo/view?usp=sharing).
Can you help me in fitting the data?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
def func(x, a, b, c,x0):
    return a*x+b*np.log((x-x0)/c)

data1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\TanviPradhan\OneDrive - EFFECT Photonics\Desktop\CD581379_A-12469303362S__GAIN_DIODE_TEST__2021-08-03_16.57.36.txt',skipinitialspace=True,comment="%")
print(data1)


#Creates one figure for the plots
fig =  plt.figure(figsize=(7,14))
fig.suptitle('Wafer xx')
#Creates the subplots 1x2 plots 1st plot is 121
ax_X= fig.add_subplot(211)
plt.xlabel("Injected Current (mA)")
plt.ylabel("Measured voltage (V)")
ax_X.set_title('xx')
#ax_X.set(xlim=(0, 80), ylim=(0, 1.5))
plt.grid(True)




#add plot for each chip to total plot

ax_X.plot(data1["InjectedCurrent(mA)"],data1["GAIN_X(V)"])

x = data1["InjectedCurrent(mA)"]
y = data1["GAIN_X(V)"]

#training the data
train_x = x[:80]
train_y = y[:80]

#testing the data
test_x = x[80:]
test_y = y[80:]

plt.scatter(train_x, train_y)
plt.show()


plt.scatter(test_x, test_y)
plt.show()

#fitting_data
params,popt = curve_fit(func,x,y,maxrev=1000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use curve_fit() with initialization of params, otherwise it is difficult to obtain correct results.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=(0, [3., 1., 0.5]))
```

Try to optimize bounds and also add p0 as start pamaters:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([a1,a2],[b1,b2]),p0=[c0,c1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ammon already mentioned, providing a reasonable initial guess, and boundaries (if possible) really helps a lot. Excluding values for x=0 might also help the function behave a little better.

```
p0 = [0.002, 0.05, 0.001, 0.0]
bounds = (
    [0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0,     0.0], # lower
    [0.1,    0.1,    0.1,     0.5], # upper
)
params, popt = curve_fit(func, x[x>0], y[x>0], p0=p0, bounds=bounds)
```

This results in the fitted parameters:

```
array([3.27556699e-03, 5.76995401e-02, 1.56406668e-05, 2.80572662e-01])
```

This is just an example, but already shows that with a reasonable initial guess, you get a pretty good fit, but still not perfect. Hopefully this shows you how to apply the `curve_fit` function.

I'm not familiar with the function you're using, so you might be able to improve by incorporating better knowledge for the initial guess and boundaries.

[image]

edit:
Complete snippet:

Imports and reading input data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.read_csv(r'D:\CD581379_A-12469303362S__GAIN_DIODE_TEST__2021-08-03_16.57.36.TXT', skipinitialspace=True, comment="%")
x = data1["InjectedCurrent(mA)"]
y = data1["GAIN_X(V)"]
```

Fitting function:

```
def func(x, a, b, c, x0):
    return a*x+b*np.log((x-x0)/c)

#fitting_data
p0 = [0.002, 0.05, 0.001, 0.0]
bounds = (
    [0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0,     0.0], # lower
    [0.1,    0.1,    0.1,     0.5], # upper
)
params, popt = curve_fit(func, x[x>0], y[x>0], p0=p0, bounds=bounds)
```

Plot result:

```
#Creates one figure for the plots
fig, ax =  plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5), constrained_layout=True, dpi=86, facecolor='w')
fig.suptitle('Wafer xx')

ax.set_xlabel("Injected Current (mA)")
ax.set_ylabel("Measured voltage (V)")
ax.set_title('xx')
ax.grid(True)

ax.plot(x, y, 'k--', label='all data')

ax.plot(x, func(x, *p0), label='init guess', lw=2)
ax.plot(x, func(x, *params), label='fit', lw=2)

ax.legend(loc=4)
```

Comment: Hi Rutger, can you share the complete code ?

Comment: @TanviPradhan, I've updated the post to include everything. But it's basically the same as your OP.